# Storing callbacks in a dictionary (Objective C for the iPhone)

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to store callbacks in a dictionary.

- I can't use blocks as the iPhone doesn't support this (unless you use plblocks).
- I tried using functions, but apparently NSMutableDictionary doesn't allow these pointers (wants an id)
- I tried using class methods, but I couldn't find a way to obtain a pointer to these
- I could try using functions with the c++ stl hashmap (if it is supported in Objective C++), but apparently this can slow compilation times.
- I could try storing both a class and a selector, but that seems rather messy.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what you are doing with pointers, you can wrap them up with NSValue.  You can then put NSValue in a dictionary.

To insert:

```
[myDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:functionName] forKey:myKey];
```

For retrieval:

```
NSValue* funcVal=(NSValue*) [myDict objectForKey:myKey];
returnType* (*func)()=[funcVal pointerValue];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can put it in an [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> An NSInvocation is an Objective-C
>   message rendered static, that is, it
>   is an action turned into an object.
>   NSInvocation objects are used to store
>   and forward messages between objects
>   and between applications, primarily by
>   NSTimer objects and the distributed
>   objects system.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your own project, why not use blocks since you can?

Comment: It is not worth adding an extra dependency just for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a single file compile using C++ if you change the extension to .mm. You don't have to change the other files in your project as long as they don't have to handle any C++ types.